# Unicode dots not rendering in the openlayers map anymore after upgrading form version 4 to 6?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I recently updated my openlayers version from 4.6.5 to the latest 6.4.3.

After adjusting all the interfaces and imports, one of the layers, which rendered fine before the migration, does not show the unicode dots anymore.

The layer creation:

```
new olLayer.Vector({
       source: new VectorSource({
                format: new olFormat.GeoJSON(),
                wrapX: this.options.tileServerLang === 'ja',
                loader: (extent: Extent) => {
                    //loader code
                },
                strategy: bbox
            }),
            style: new olStyle.Style({
                text: new olStyle.Text({
                    text: '\u25CF',
                    font: '12px FontAwesome',
                    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
                    fill: new olStyle.Fill({
                        color: 'black'
                    })
                }),
                zIndex: LayerFactory.zIndexes.data
            }),
            zIndex: LayerFactory.zIndexes.data,
            className: 'ol-layer dot-density'
        });
```

Looking into the features, it turns out, that

1. the style for the features is correct (see 'text' property below is a unicode dot)
2. there are features added to the source

[image]

Some additional info:

1. this has worked on openlayers 4
2. other layers render just fine (e.g. the heatmap)

Is there something missing? What could be the reason for those chars not showing up?

Comment: Looks to me like it doesn't like `textBaseline: 'Bottom',`.  Per the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html),  possible values are: 'bottom', 'top', 'middle', 'alphabetic', 'hanging', 'ideographic'.  If I change it to 'bottom', the "dot" appears.

Comment: hey @geocodezip, sorry i forgot to answer! 

Yes, thats it. strange that the capitalization changed with teh version. Anyway, thanks a lot!